# In SublimeText2, how to choose which .py file to build rather than the opened one?

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I often have many files open in multiple tabs in SublimeText2. Say I have 2 files, main.py and helper.py. While I am editing helper.py, how can I build main.py without switching tab to the file I want to build?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new Build System and replace **$file** with your **"main.py"**.

In **" Tools > Build System > New Build System... "** put this code in:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "main.py"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Save it with some name, e.g. **"Python(main.py).sublime-build"**. Now **Python(main.py)** will appear in your Build System list. Select it and hit cmd+B to build, now you will always build using your "main.py" :)

Answer (score 2):

What @Hlung said will work, but I think it would be better if you created a project specific build system (which are stored inside project configurations). This way, your always-execute-main-file build system is only active for when you have that project open. If you are just editing single scripts that you want to execute, you wont have to manually switch the build system to run them.

Here's an example of a `*.sublime-project` file that I use which contains a project specific build system:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "app",
            "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.sublime-*"],
            "folder_exclude_patterns": ["__pycache__"]
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "tab_size": 4,
        "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
    },
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "cmd": ["python", "-u", "${project_path}/main.py"],
            "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
            "selector": "source.python",
            "shell": true
        }
    ]
}
```

You can find more info on build systems [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html)

Comment: I put that code in my `*.sublime-project` but it always error when I save. **"Error trying to parse project: Trailing comma before closing bracket"**. However, it is saved to disk, but when I run it, it doesn't use `main.py` to build :/

Comment: Oops, my bad... I cut out some unnecessary parts before pasting that in and it had some extra commas which invalidated the JSON string. Try the edited version...